# Website is stuck in redirect loop

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, https, base-url

After changing **Base URL** to `https` & **Base Link URL** to `{{secure_base_url}}` in `Admin > System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure`,  website is stuck in redirect loop !

> This webpage has a redirect loop ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS message

Now I can't access to the site and admin panel.

Answer (score 6):

Found the solution. Accessed the `core_config_data` table via `phpMyAdmin`, and

removed the value of `web/cookie/cookie_domain` and `set web/cookie/cookie_httponly` to **0**.

Cleared the cache by removing the files in **var/cache**. Site's back up :)

Comment: Its works for me 40 default 0 web/cookie/cookie_httponly 0
39 default 0 web/cookie/cookie_domain 0

Answer (score 1):

If you can access your database through your cPanel, find the core_config_data table, and update your URL's there under web/unsecure/base_url, and web/secure/base_url. Not sure why you're getting that redirect (maybe a .htaccess issue), but at least you should be able to change your URL's back without using the Magento admin panel.

Comment: I made the suggested changes and flushed the cache but still get the redirect error. Is there something in the .htaccess file that might need to be changed/added?

Comment: In `.htaccess`, `RewriteBase` is something to check out if you've renamed the Magento root directory or moved it a level.