# 301 redirect loop on category view

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, category-view

when I try to access a category page, I get the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS caused by 301 redirects. Also trying by not rewritten url (like "catalog/category/view/id/309"), the result is the same. Instead I have no issue on other routes as product view or checkout/cart.

I have already tried the steps described in this [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/76190/website-is-stuck-in-redirect-loop) post.
Can you suggest me how to debug this issue?

Thanks